# Why $\arctan x \to \pi/2$ when $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit of $\arctan x$ as $x \to +\infty$ is $\pi/2$. Maybe I don't understand the arctan enough, because by looking at the graph I see that indeed it approaches pi. But: why? How can I understand that?

Comment: Because $\tan(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \pi/2-$.  (note that it's $\pi/2$ and not $\pi$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\tan{x}$ is the ratio of the opposite side to the adjacent side in a right angled triangle.

[image]

As angle $A\to\ \pi/2$, the opposite side tends to $\infty$, while the adjacent side is fixed, so since $\tan{A}=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$, $\tan{A} \to\infty$.

Obviously then as $\arctan(x)\to\pi/2$, $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
as angle increases in quadrant 1 tan become increases 
and vice a versa